# Перенос файлов из ftp в репозитарий

Tags: git, github

Доброго времени суток! Недавно стал использовать git и столкнулся со следующей задачкой, на ftp есть файлы, как их перенести сразу в репозитарий github?

Comment: Задача не позволяет скопировать на локальную машину через FTP, а затем залить в репозиторий?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-file-to-a-repository/

Answer (score 1):

Как ни странно, на удаленном репозитории в GitHub ваших файлов нет. Вместо них есть контентно-адресуемая файловая система / база данных, в которой хранятся бинарные файлы, из которых можно однозначным образом восстановить ваши файлы. Эти бинарные файлы называются блобами (BLOB - Binary Large OBject). Как zip-архив, только посложнее. Чтобы не работать со всем этим вручную, поверх была реализована система контроля версий с более высокоуровневыми функциями.

Поэтому напрямую через протокол ftp файлы на удаленный репозиторий отправить нельзя. Нужно сначала преобразовать их в нужный формат.

Ваша задача разбивается на несколько:

1. Скопировать файлы с фтп на свою локальную машину (думаю, пояснения не нужны). Но если у вас есть удаленный доступ к серверу с FTP, можете и там работать.
2. Добавить их и сделать коммит
3. Отправить (запушить) на гитхаб.

Расскажу о процессе подробнее, чтобы было понятно, почему нельзя сразу FTP -> Git.

```
git status
```

Git сравнивает структуру и содержимое 1) файлов в рабочей области 2) представлений файлов в собственном хранилище. По каждому несоответствию показывает результат: путь и имя файла, суть несоответствия (появился, удален, поменялся, ещё не отслеживали). Удобная команда, позволяющая сориентироваться в происходящем - но для сохранения файлов она необязательна.

```
git add .
```

Git читает указанные файлы, преобразует их в блобы, организованные в дерево (направленный ациклический граф) и формирует индекс - специальный список файлов, которые войдут в следующий коммит. Бинарники хранятся вместе с прочими в общей файловой системе, но индекс - отдельно от коммитов.

Вместо точки может быть путь и/или имена файлов.

```
git commit -m 'комментарий к коммиту'
```

Git берет индекс, добавляет к нему дату, имя автора и некоторые другие данные и формирует из него объект "коммит". В коммите также всегда есть ссылка на предыдущий, "родительский" коммит (иногда их бывает два и больше). Теперь этот коммит становится частью общего дерева коммитов. В нём хранятся ссылки на блобы, которые раньше были в индексе и в предыдущем коммите, а индекс обнуляется. Указатель текущей ветки перемещается на вновь созданный коммит.

```
git push
```

Git устанавливает соединение с удаленным сервером и "проталкивает" на него новые изменения. Если удаленный сервер уже имеет какой-то коммит, то повторно он не будет передаваться. Как мы уже знаем, каждый коммит ссылается на дерево блобов. При передаче коммита сверяется всё его содержимое. Если удалённый сервер получает новый коммит, но уже имеет какой-то из блобов, то этот блоб также не будет передаваться.

Comment: Написал немного наспех, могут быть ошибки или неточности. Критика приветствуется. )

Comment: в интерфейсе github есть кнопка [upload files](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-file-to-a-repository/), с помощью которой локальные файлы можно «как бы добавлять» в репозиторий. так что вопрос (в данном случае) сводится лишь к тому, можно ли примонтировать каталог с ftp-сервера так, чтобы файлы в нём выглядели для браузера локальными. в unix-like системах это можно сделать. в *ms/windows* — увы, не знаю.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ну вот, я чувствую себя старпером. Не знаю о новых модных хипстерских фичах. )

Comment: да я сам узнал об этом 8 часов назад (см. мой комментарий под вопросом). потому и не стал писать ответ. (я бы назвал эту «фичу» не «хипстерской», а «домохозяйкинской»).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin  ftpdrive в помощь. Ну и ntfs-линки (mklink /D)  Натравить их на локальный репозитарий, да дать коммит. Должно сработать.