# Можно ли как-то загрузить папку на русском языке в GitHub?

Tags: git, github

Через интерфейс хотел загрузить проект **в GitHub** репозиторий. Все идет успешно до момента загрузки папки с именем "Темы игры". Потом Github зависает. При переименовании на "Themes of game" проблема исчезает.

Можно ли каким то образом загружать **папки**, имя которых записано **на русском**?

Comment: какой git-клиент (версия)? Какая ОСь?

Comment: в принципе — не возбраняется, конечно, но **для совместимости** с разными файловыми системами в именах файлов/каталогов, хранящихся в **любой** системе контроля версий, всё-таки лучше воздерживаться от употребления символов, не входящих в набор `[-_.A-Za-z0-9]`.

Comment: Это не гитхаб зависает, а ваш клиент. ) А еще, что вы понимаете под загрузкой папки?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, скорее всего, подразумевается [та самая «фича»](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/523926/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-ftp-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9/524028#comment648398_524028)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ха, может быть и о ней речь. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin да, используется фича "Upload file" прямо из сайта GitHub

Comment: @alexanderbarakin угадали!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никаких проблем.
Скорее всего у вас проблема с git-клиентом[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо большое, через git-клиент у меня получилось. Жалко, что через фичу "Upload files"  на GitHub не выгружаются папки на русском. Интересно это баг?:)